# Kafka Stream: output to a topic first or persist directly?

Tags: apache-kafka, persistence, apache-kafka-streams

A fair number of articles describe implementing the use of Kafka Streams where they output to a new Kafka topic instead of saving to some sort of distributed database.

Is this just a common use case, making the assumption that the embedded db + interactive queries is sufficient, or is there some architectural reason why one would want to output a topic before consuming it again to persist it, instead of persisting directly?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the context of the examples I'm looking at is for tumbling time-windowed aggregation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want is to take data out of kafka and store it in a db, then Kafka Connect is the most natural way to go.

On the other hand if your primary use-case is doing aggregation, then indeed Kafka Streams is an easy and elegant way to go about it. And if a Kafka Connect sink already exists for your preferred database, then it will be most straightforward to have Kafka Streams write output to a topic and then have that Kafka Connect sink pick it up and store in your db. If no out-of-the-box sink exists and you have to write it and you don't think it would be reusable enough, then you might choose to just write it as a custom Kafka Streams processor and not have an output Kafka topic.

As you can see there are various ways to go depending on your use-case and your preferences. There is no one correct way, so please consider the trade-offs involved.